# webApi not returning associated entities from custom POCO

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am creating a webapi to return data. I have built the following product/sub-product class and hard coding data. When I test the api, only product info is returned. No mention of child product. What am I missing? Here is the code:
POCO Class:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {

    }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public List<SubProduct> SubProducts { get; private set; } = new List<Domain.SubProduct>();
}

public class SubProduct
{
    public SubProduct()
    {
        Plans = new List<Plan>();
    }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public string SubProductCode { get; set; }
}
```

web api controller code:

```
public class OdsDataController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetTestData()
    {
        List<Domain.Product> returnData = new List<Domain.Product>();
        returnData.Add(new Domain.Product { ProductCode = "123" });
        returnData.First().SubProducts.Add(new Domain.SubProduct { SubProductCode = "1255" });
        return Ok(returnData);
    }
}
```

In browser when I hit this method I get:
http://localhost:56459/api/OdsData/gettestdata

[{"ProductCode":"123"}]

Even in fiddler, I see only ProductCode

Any idea why am I not getting sub-product information? Am I missing anything obvious?
Thanks
D

Answer (score 0):

Don't make sense to me but I had to add Serializable and DataContract attribute on the class..and on the property, I had to add DataMember attribute. Then it worked as expected.
Here is the code for others ..if needed:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {

    }
    [DataMember]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<SubProduct> SubProducts { get; private set; } = new List<Domain.SubProduct>();
}
```